# SQL Server 2008 Express 32-bit Import and Export Wizard installation

Tags: import, sql-server-2008-express

My first post on StackOverflow, so please excuse me if I am being ignorant.

Lately, I have been playing around with MS Visual Web Developer for work purpose, and I have installed the 2008 Express edition on both my home and work computers.

I only later found out that the import and export wizard for the 2 computers are different: at work I have the 64 bit version and at home I have the 32 bit version. This is causing me tremendous amount of headaches as I was hoping to rely on its functionality to import Access and Excel files which only offers under the 32 bit version.

My question: Is there any way I can install this 32 bit wizard at work separately without having to reinstall the whole MS VWD application? Perhaps as an add-on or service pack or something?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server, install SQL Server Management Studio and do you importing/exporting through it.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593